# Sort entries per category

Tags: entries, categories, sorting

I have a collection of entries in a structure, and each entry can be in multiple categories.

Is it possible to sort the entries seperately for each category?

So it would look something like this:

```
Category 1: entry 1, entry 2, entry 3
Category 2: entry 3, entry 2, entry 4
```

There seems to be lots of very similar questions here already, but none that are exactly like this, and I can't figure out how to do it. Can someone please help?

Comment: What determines the order for the entries in a category? in your example you have `Category 2: entry 3, entry 2, entry 4`but what makes entry 2 come between 3 and 4?

Comment: Well, nothing currently, that's what I'm looking for - a way to order the entries. Thanks for your response, it looks like the suggestion from carlcs below is probably the way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but your question sounds like you currently don’t even have something set up in the CMS that determines the order the entries should be listed under each category, and the reason for this probably is that you are using a Categories field assigned to the entries’ field layout.

What I am suggesting is to reverse that setup. An Entries field on your category’s field layout not only allows to select which entries you want to relate to each category, but also in which order they should be listed.

Before implementing this you better check if this reversed setup does also make sense for the data entry, but the fact that you’re interested in the sort order is an indication that this might be the case.

Comment: Both you and Michael Rosmane above are correct, what I am looking for is a way to order the entries in each category, I don't currently have it.

I think this idea of reversing the categorisation is probably the best I am going to get - rather than going into an entry and adding it to a category, I go into the category and add all the relevant entries to that category, and can then sort them from there. Thanks for your help.